# Using nested for-loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm trying to use for loop.

If the input is 3, the result going to be:

```
1**
*2*
**3
```

So I used this code

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string message = " ";
    int value = numericUpDown1.Value;
    for(int count = 0; count < value; count++) {
        for(int m = -2; m < value; m++) {
            message += "*";
        }
        message += "\r\n";
    }
    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

I used the two for-loops but i could not fix it to show the number,
but it give me

```
***
***
***
```

Comment: forgot to tag it as homework ?

Comment: Your number will be your count variable +1

Answer (score 3):

```
int digitCount = 3;
string message = " ";
for (int round = 1; round <= digitCount; round++)
{
    for (int digit = 1; digit <= digitCount; digit++)
    {
        if (digit == round)
        {
            message += digit;
        }
        else
        {
            message += "*";
        }
    }

    message += "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: declare this instead string message;

Answer (score 1):

```
private string StarNumbers(int input)
    {
        var range = Enumerable.Range(1, input);
        var sb = new StringBuilder(input*input);
        foreach (var number in range)
        {
            var line = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", new string('*', number - 1), number, new string('*', input - number));
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

**EDIT:**

This code for input=500 : 2ms

(5ms for input 1 000)

Code using += string concatenation for input=500 :  33 468ms  (all it does is garbage collection)

(running it for several minutes for input 1 000 and still nothing)

Comment: Your proposed solution is over engineered and harder to read thus more prone to bugs.  Also, your String.Format uses more resources than concatenating string in such a simple scenario.  The size of your declared string builder is off by a constant equal to 2xinput, thus it needs to be expanded, thus taking extra resources (you didn't account for new lines).  Simplicity is king.

Comment: Actually you are wrong in the resources thing, you can easily measure the difference ;)

Comment: The stringbuilder needs to be expanded just once, with += new string is created each time.

Comment: For Fun: You can measure the difference because you've read the String.Format code?  Analyzed the work that is required to parse out your place holders and re-concatenate the strings for you?  I didn't care enough to correct every mistake you made but a "non-beginner" would perform three appends to the string builder which is optimized for concatenating strings. P.S. Your solution is still overkill.

Comment: :) I fixed the loop of someone who appears to be learning to code with requirements which by all accounts appear trivial. At no point did I claim my solution to be optimized, note the simple scenario statement above.  I do however claim that any solution which has the .Net framework create an enumeration with a for-each loop is overkill.  Wait, is that three legitimate reasons for overkill...  Humm... :)